# how do I know solve using constructors

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

Modify the following Class to Print “My App” using two different way:

-Using constructors. 
-Using method override.

```
abstract class Application{
    public abstract String getName();
}

class DefaultApplication extends Application
{
    public static final String NAME = "defapp";

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
}

class MyApp extends DefaultApplication
{
    public static final String NAME = "myapp";
}

public class Applicationtest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application myApp = new MyApp();
        System.out.println(myApp.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can not return a value. So just add a constructor to the `MyApp` class.

```
abstract class Application {
    protected Application() {
        System.out.println("default Constructor");
    }
    //constructer only can be called by child class using super keyword
    protected  Application(String appName) {
        System.out.println(appName);
    }
    public abstract String getName();
}

class DefaultApplication extends Application {
    public static final String NAME = "defapp";

    public DefaultApplication() {
        super("abstract contructor : " + NAME);
        System.out.println(NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }
}

class MyApp extends DefaultApplication {
    public static final String NAME = "myapp";

    public MyApp() {
        System.out.println(NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: I make class  myapp abstract , in constructor I do exactly like what u do and still error

Comment: thank u so much and I apologize for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Application{
    public abstract String getName();
}

class DefaultApplication extends Application
{
    public static final String NAME = "defapp";

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
}

class MyApp extends DefaultApplication
{
    public static final String NAME = "myapp";

    public MyApp()
    {
        System.out.println(NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
}

public class Applicationtest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application myApp = new MyApp();
        System.out.println(myApp.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the name of the file you've to it to?

Comment: u mean the package?

Comment: I save all these classes in same package , it's wrong ?

Comment: A file. It must be called `Applicationtest.java`:
`
javac Applicationtest.java
java Applicationtest
myapp
myapp
`

Comment: thank u so much and I apologize for wasting your time :)